# Even or odd function. Fourrier coefficients

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This is probably a very easy question, but I can't find the answer to it..

I'm working on Fourier coefficients and whether or not the integrals become zero. As far as i'm concerned this integral below equals zero due to it being odd over the interval -pi to pi. That is fair, but is it an easy way of noticing that the function is odd when it has 3 terms or more?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: The product of odd and even is odd. The product of odd and odd is even. The product of even and even is even. So $\sin(10x)$ is odd, and the other two terms are even, so the product is odd.

Comment: But another way of seeing this is to use the explicit formula $$\sin(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b)\right)$$ so $\sin(10x)\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(11x)-\sin(9x)\right)$, which gives the explicit Fourier series for $\sin(10x)\cos x$, which has no $\cos$ terms.

Comment: Thanks alot! very helpful. :)

Comment: I'll make those comments an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is odd and $g(x)$ is even (or visa versa) then $f(x)g(x)$ is odd.

If $f(x)$ is even and $g(x)$ is even, then $f(x)g(x)$ is even.

If $f(x)$ is odd and $g(x)$ is odd, then $f(x)g(x)$ is even.

This particular example can be seen by using the formula: $$\sin(a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b)\right)$$

Then $$\sin(10x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(11x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(9x)$$

Which gives us the Fourier series for $\sin(10x)\cos(x)$, which contains no $\cos$ terms.